# need help using PCRE in snort

Tags: snort

Can someone guide me how to write PCRE option to match list of websites such as for eg facebook.com, google.com,ebay.com? I tried to understand from manual but couldn't get is right?
regards,

Comment: It would help if you show what you have tried so far. Please also mention what type of traffic you are trying to match. DNS? TLS SNI? HTTP?

Comment: hi david, i tried following way = pcre:"/\facebook|\google\.com/i";  but this shows following error= pcre compile of "\facebook|\google\.com" failed at offset 11 : a numbered reference must not be zero.

Comment: Have you tried removing the backslash before the `f` and `g`? There should be no need for this.